# Get access token by non-Microsoft user credentials without prompt

Tags: c#, azure-active-directory

I’m trying to get an access token for **non-microsoft** user **without prompt**.

It worked for me with prompt:
`authenticationContext.AcquireToken(resource, clientId, new Uri(uri), PromptBehavior.Always);`

But without prompt it didn't work. I tried the 2 following ways:

1. `var authContext = new AuthenticationContext(Authority);
   var userCredential = new UserCredential(username, password);
   var token = authContext.AcquireToken(resource, clientId, userCredential);`

   ActiveDirectory v3 exception: Accessing WS metadata exchange failed.

   ActiveDirectory v2: sequence contains no elements.
2. `new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, "https://login.microsoftonline.com/<tenantId>/oauth2/token");`

   With:

   `$"grant_type=password&resource={resource}&client_id=
   {clientId}&username={userName}&password={password}"`

   Error description: "AADSTS50034: To sign into this application the account must be added to the *tenantId* directory.

The user I used is in the tenant I'm trying to login, and it worked with prompt.
I wonder why it doesn't work for the 2 other ways.

Thanks

Comment: What does "non-Microsoft" user mean? What are you trying to accomplish by not having a prompt?

Comment: For example: xxx@outlook.com. With Microsoft user like xxx@microsoft.com it works. (They both are in the same tenant). I'd like to pass the user credentials dynamically (no user actions)

Comment: How has xxx@outlook.com been added to the tenant? As a Guest account? or an External Account? Are you using a standard AAD Application created by the Azure Portal?

Comment: Guest account. and yes - a standard AAD Application created by the Azure Portal

Answer (score 0):

The problem here might simply be that the "username" for the guest account is not "xxx@outlook.com". When a guest account is created in AAD from an MSA account (like @outlook.com or @live.com), a new AAD User is generated with a unique User Principal Name which will look something like this:

```
    {
        "id": "d3ce3d26-xxx-xxx-xxx-5157f5308f04",
        "businessPhones": [],
        "displayName": "Shawn Tabrizi",
        "givenName": "Shawn",
        "jobTitle": null,
        "mail": null,
        "mobilePhone": null,
        "officeLocation": null,
        "preferredLanguage": null,
        "surname": "Tabrizi",
        "userPrincipalName": "shawntabrizi_live.com#EXT#@shawntest.onmicrosoft.com"
    },
```

Note the 'weird' formatting of the `userPrincipalName`. You can see this is a guest account created for my @live.com account. I got this by making the following call in my tenant:

```
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users
```

The solution here is probably to populate the username field with the `userPrincipalName` value, which is what AAD knows and expects as the Unique ID for the user, rather than the original MSA Username.

The next natural question is why does the xxx@outlook.com account work for sign in via the interactive login experience? Well there is probably a lot of 'magic' happening in that page which cannot be replicated using the Resource Owner Password Credentials Grant in Azure Active Directory.

Let me know if this solves the problem.

Comment: I have only unique_name, and tried it, but it failed.

Comment: What do you mean 'unique_name'? Where is that value coming from?

Comment: Thanks you Shawn! unique_name - live.com#xxx@outlook.com. AFAIK, guest user has no UPN. I see unique_name in the login request.

Comment: Hi Michal, I recently played around with some more GUEST user stuff, and I can confirm that the token you get for a guest user does not contain a `upn` claim, but a `unique_name` claim. If you query the user object, like with the `/me` endpoint, you will see the real `userPrincipalName` in the response: `"userPrincipalName":"shtabriz_microsoft.com#EXT#@shawntest.onmicrosoft.com"` or similar. I believe (have not tested yet) that you should be using this identifier for the Resource Owner Password Credentials Grant.